# Update embedded models in Loopback 4

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I have the following model relationship in my LoopBack 4 application:
A Survey has 1-many relationship with Question,
Question has 1-many relationship with Option.

Am using MongoDB as the database. I am unable to figure out how to implement a PUT/PATCH REST api, that can update the entire Survey model containing the Questions and Options. I get the following exception when i try a PATCH on the sample request JSON below:

> Exception:  Unhandled error in PATCH /5be3e00aad0df83d10e580d1: 500
>   TypeError: Class constructor Question cannot be invoked without 'new'
>       at Function.DataAccessObject._coerce (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\dao.js:1799:22)
>       at doUpdate (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\dao.js:2735:20)
>       at C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\dao.js:2714:11
>       at doNotify (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)
>       at doNotify (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)
>       at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:178:5)
>       at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:153:8)
>       at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:176:15)
>       at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:153:8)
>       at C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\dao.js:2699:11
>       at doNotify (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)
>       at doNotify (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)
>       at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:178:5)
>       at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:153:8)
>       at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:176:15)
>       at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (C:\Users\nk\Documents\Project\backend\surveyService\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:153:8)

Sample PATCH request:

```
[{
    "title": "Some survey title 1",
    "description": "Some survey title 1",
    "questions": [{
        "options": [{
            "description": "Some option description 1",
            "type": "Option"
        }],
        "description": "Some question description 1"
    }]
}]
```

Have not been able to find any helpful information on this yet. Any pointers please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have most likely discovered a bug/missing feature of LB4. Can you open a GitHub issue please? https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues

Comment: Thank you for your response Miroslav! Yes, i think i will have to do that.